# RxJS - POST multipart files

Tags: post, rxjs, multipart

I'm doing a POST of multipart files.  When the files are small (2 files of 50kb).  Everything works fine.
When files are bigger (10 files of 500kb), it's not working properly.
I think the reason is the POST takes a while to return a result.

First, I'm merging two obs via merge which invokes the POST.
Secondly, I do get the uploadDocumentDetails$ via conmbineLatest uploadDocumentsSaved and the behaviorSubject action uploadDocumentGetDetailsAction.

As a result of invoking to fast the uploadDocumentGetDetailsAction, the POST has not finished yet.

How should I implement the obs to obtain the GET after the POST has finished first?

```
  uploadDocumentsSaved$ = merge(
    this.uploadedDocuments$,
    this.saveAction$
      .pipe(
        concatMap(uploadDocument => {
          return  this.saveUploadDocuments(uploadDocument);
        })
      ))
      .pipe(
        scan((uploadDocuments: UploadDocument[], uploadDocument: UploadDocument) =>
          this.syncUploadDocuments(uploadDocuments, uploadDocument)
        ),
        shareReplay(1)
    );

  uploadDocumentDetails$ = combineLatest([
    this.uploadDocumentsSaved$,
    this.uploadDocumentGetDetailsAction$
  ]).pipe(
    map(([uploadedDocuments, selectedUploadedDocument]) =>
      uploadedDocuments.find(uploadedDocument => uploadedDocument.type = selectedUploadedDocument)
    ),
    switchMap(uploadDocument => this.uploadDocumentDetailsUrl(uploadDocument.token, uploadDocument.type)),
    shareReplay(1),
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand what the shown code does, but would something like this work:

```
  uploadDocumentsSaved$ = merge(
    this.uploadedDocuments$,
    this.saveAction$
      .pipe(
        concatMap(uploadDocument => this.saveUploadDocuments(uploadDocument)),
        concatMap(uploadDocument => this.uploadDocumentDetailsUrl(uploadDocument.token, uploadDocument.type))
      ))
      .pipe(
        scan((uploadDocuments: UploadDocument[], uploadDocument: UploadDocument) =>
          this.syncUploadDocuments(uploadDocuments, uploadDocument)
        ),
        shareReplay(1)
    );
```

Each time the saveAction occurs, this will first call `saveUploadDocuments` (which I assume does the post) and *then* call the `uploadDocumentDetailsUrl`.